# How to force script to use different version of python and modules installed by anaconda inside home folder of other user?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

The problem is that server version is python 2.6 and I do not have administrator privileges to install Anaconda for other user than me (here crm_batch). Is it posssible to take advantage of my installation?
I am trying to run python script by other user than me by my anaconda and its packages.
I have changed envs variable inside bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o allexport
PATH="/home/129175/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
PYTHONPATH=/home/129175/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-package‌​‌s:/home/129175/anac‌​o‌​nda3/lib:/home/12‌​917‌​5/anaconda3:/ho‌​me/12‌​9175/anaconda‌​3/lib64
export PYTHONPATH
PYTHONHOME=/home/129175/anaconda3/lib/python3.5
export PYTHONHOME
set -v
echo $PATH
echo $PYTHONHOME
echo $PYTHONPATH
echo $USER
which python
python /BD/CRM/batch/DCI_ZAIK/python/print.py
```

Here is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import encodings
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

And finally output from the bash script:

```
+ user=crm_batch
+ sudo -iu crm_batch -- bash /BD/CRM/batch/DCI_ZAIK/bin/shellcode/python_send_mail.sh
echo $PATH
/home/129175/anaconda3/bin:/opt/teradata/client/15.00/tbuild/bin64:/home/129175/anaconda3/bin:/app/oh12c/client_1/bin:/home/crm_batch/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin
echo $PYTHONHOME
/home/129175/anaconda3/lib/python3.5
echo $PYTHONPATH
/home/129175/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages:/home/129175/anaconda3/lib:/home/129175/anaconda3:/home/129175/anaconda3/lib64
echo $USER
crm_batch
which python
/home/129175/anaconda3/bin/python
python /BD/CRM/batch/DCI_ZAIK/python/print.py
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I would appreciate for any help.
There is additional thing to be mentioned here, the bash script is executed from BMC Control-M. But in my opinion it does not affect the output at all.

Peter

Comment: there is also "conda execute" which is not written by continuum. `https://github.com/pelson/conda-execute`

Comment: Sorry @JohnZwinck for previous comment, my question has been reedited.